# Trigger Istio Circuit Breaker based on % of 5xxErrors

Tags: istio, circuit-breaker, servicemesh

I was reading up [the documentation for Istio circuit breaker](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/). I see that for a given interval we can set up a numerical value of `consecutive5xxErrors` (and check few other settings) for the circuit breaking action to take effect.

I wanted to know if it was possible to somehow do circuit breaking in Istio based on the % of `5xxerrors` vs normal connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on the documentation that you've already found:

- *[Istio.io: Latest: Docs: Reference: Config: Networking: Destination Rule: Outlier Detection](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#OutlierDetection)*

As you can see there are specific fields for the `outlierDetection`:

- `consecutiveGatewayErrors`
- `consecutive5xxErrors`
- `interval`
- `baseEjectionTime`
- `maxEjectionPercent`
- `minHealthPercent`

The field that will force the request to not hit particular object is: `consecutive5xxErrors`.

As also it can be seen in the documentation:

| Field | Type | Description | Required |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| consecutive5xxErrors | UInt32Value | Number of 5xx errors before a host is ejected from the connection pool. When the upstream host is accessed over an opaque TCP connection, connect timeouts, connection error/failure and request failure events qualify as a 5xx error. This feature defaults to 5 but can be disabled by setting the value to 0. | No |

> -- *[Istio.io: Latest: Docs: Reference: Config: Networking: Destination Rule: Outlier Detection](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#OutlierDetection)*

**The value for it is flat and cannot be used as a percentage.**

---

I found the feature request on the github page of `Istio` that I think is referencing the feature that you would like to run:

- *[Github.com: Istio: Issues: OutlierDetection: support success rate and fixed failure percentage](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19052)*

---

I'd reckon you could try to use an `EnvoyFilter` to modify the configuration of `Envoy` (haven't tested it) as `Envoy` itself has some fields related to the percentages of failures/successes. The documentation that should help you:

- *[Istio.io: Latest: Docs: Reference: Config: Networking: Envoy filter](https://istio.io/latest/docs/referenc44e/config/networking/envoy-filter/)*
- *[Envoyproxy.io: Docs: Envoy: Latest: Intro: Architecture overview: Upstream: Failure percentage](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/upstream/outlier.html#failure-percentage)*
- *[Envoyproxy.io: Docs: Envoy: Latest: Api v3: Config: Cluster: v3: Outlier detection](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/cluster/v3/outlier_detection.proto)*